# Pandas drop duplicate base on 2 columns, having differents value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

How to drop duplicate in that specific way:

```
Index B C
1     2 1
2     2 0
3     3 1
4     3 1
5     4 0
6     4 0 
7     4 0
8     5 1
9     5 0
10    5 1
```

Desired output :

```
Index B C
3     3 1
5     4 0
```

So dropping duplicate on B but if C is the same on all row and keep one sample/record.

For example, B = 3 for index 3/4 but since C = 1 for both, I do not destroy them all

But for example B = 5 for index 8/9/10 since C = 1 or 0, it get destroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `transform` with `nunique` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df[df.groupby('B')['C'].transform('nunique') == 1].drop_duplicates(subset='B')
```

Output:

```
       B  C
Index      
3      3  1
5      4  0
```

Comment: On the drop duplicates part I need to put subset='B' but yeah thats solved it for me thanks !

Comment: @HadrienBerthier Great.  Be safe and stay healthy.